# How to create a table of equations with descriptions?

Tags: html, css, html-table, alignment, mathjax

I'd like to create a borderless table of equations, with equations numbered and equal signs aligned:
[image]
In place of the equal signs, I'd like to insert colored and scaled Unicode characters - namely a larger red `⬌` (equivalence). Lastly, descriptions inline with the equations - preferably on the right.

I tried centering equations, but the equal signs and numberings don't align as intended - and aligning either one or the other takes row-specific spacing:

```html
<script type="text/javascript" async src=
"https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.5/latest.js?config=
TeX-MML-AM_CHTML"></script>
<center><p>
\([1]\hspace{63px} 1 + 2 = 3\)<br>
\([2]\ \ 1 + 3 + 5= 9 + 0\)
</p></center>
```

(Didn't get far in adding descriptions without a messy code.)

How can this be accomplished?

Comment: MathJax has the `&` alignment command. Use `&=` instead of `=`, and use something other than `\(\)`. You can have aligned tables or arrays in MathJax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can create such a table using some HTML & CSS.

Start with a basic table, toss in some CSS to set table width, add borders, and align text:

```css
table {width: 300px;border-collapse: collapse;}
table, td, th {border-bottom: 1px solid black;}
.ctr {text-align: center;}
.lft {text-align: right;}
.rgt {text-align: left}
```

```html
<table>
    <tr><td>[1]</td>
    <td class="lft">3 - 2</td>
    <td class="ctr">=</td>
    <td class="rgt">1</td></tr>

    <tr><td>[2]</td>
    <td class="lft">4 + 1 - 3</td>
    <td class="ctr">=</td>
    <td class="rgt">6 - 4</td></tr>                                                     
</table>
```

LHS takes up a lot more space than RHS; to even it out, add inline styles to the *top column only*:

```html
<tr><td style="width: 10%">[1]</td>
<td class="lft" style="width: 40%">3 - 2</td>
<td class="ctr" style="width: 10%">=</td>
<td class="rgt" style="width: 40%">1</td></tr>

<tr><td>[2]</td>
<td class="lft">4 + 1 - 3</td>
<td class="ctr">=</td>
<td class="rgt">6 - 4</td></tr>
```

[[Above result]](https://jsfiddle.net/58uL430k/1/) To space rows vertically, add `td {padding-top: 6px;}`
[[Result]](https://jsfiddle.net/58uL430k/3/)
To add styled Unicode, replace `=` with `& #11020 ;` (no spaces), and modify `.ctr` to

```
.ctr {text-align: center; line-height: 100%; font-size: 150%; color: red}
```

[[Above result]](https://jsfiddle.net/58uL430k/5/)(`text-align: center`vertically aligns the symbol with the rest of the text, after derailing due to `font-resize`)

Finishing off with a header & descriptions, we add an additional row and column, and adjust widths:

```html
<tr style="border-bottom: 1px solid black; font-weight: bold">
<td style="width: 10%">Eq</td>
<td class="lft" style="width:20%">LHS</td>
<td style="10%"></td>
<td class="rgt" style="width:20%">RHS</td>
<td>Description</td></tr>

<tr><td>[1]</td>
<td class="lft">3 - 2</td>
<td class="ctr">&#11020;</td>
<td class="rgt">1</td>
<td>More arithmetic</td>
</tr>

<tr><td>[2]</td>
<td class="lft">4 + 1 - 3</td>
<td class="ctr">&#11020;</td>
<td class="rgt">6 - 4</td>
<td>Wider arithmetic</td></tr>
```

[[Above result]](https://jsfiddle.net/58uL430k/8/) To rid of borders, remove from CSS

```
table, td, th {border-bottom: 1px solid black;}
```

Lastly, beef the fancy further, add a math library and define a new command to easily style the enumeration:

```html
<script type="text/javascript" async src=
"https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.5/latest.js?config=
TeX-MML-AM_CHTML"></script>
<p style="display:none">\(\newcommand{b}[1]{\boldsymbol{[#1]}}\)</p>
```

**FINISHED PRODUCT:**

```css
table {
    width: 400px;
    border-collapse: collapse;   
}
table, td, th {border-bottom: 1px solid black;}
.ctr {text-align: center; line-height: 100%; font-size: 150%; color: red}
.lft {text-align: right;}
.rgt {text-align: left}
 td {padding-top: 6px;}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" async src=
"https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.5/latest.js?config=
TeX-MML-AM_CHTML"></script>
<p style="display:none">\(\newcommand{b}[1]{\boldsymbol{[#1]}}\)</p>

<table>

<tr style="border-bottom: 1px solid black; font-weight: bold">
<td style="width: 10%">\(Eq\)</td><td class="lft" style="width:18%">
LHS
</td><td class="ctr" style="width: 13%"></td><td class="rgt" style="width:20%">
RHS
</td><td>Description</td></tr>
   
<tr><td>\(\b{2}\)</td><td class="lft">
\(3 - 2\)
</td><td class="ctr">&#11020;</td><td class="rgt">
\(1\)
</td><td>More arithmetic</td></tr>
  
<tr><td>\(\b{4}\)</td><td class="lft">
\(E\)
</td><td class="ctr">&#11020;</td><td class="rgt">
\(mc^2\)
</td><td><i>FEEL THE ENERGY</i></td></tr>

</table>
```

(As a bonus, I rewrote the HTML for simplicity; this way, LHS and RHS are easy to spot and edit, and new rows can be created by copy/pasting the five-line blocks.)

---

... aand we are done. Hope it's useful.

Now go hammer some math tables.

---

**NOTE:** See scraaappy's answer for a possibly simpler alternative using MathJax arrays.

Answer (score 1):

You should though explore mathjax (latex) powerfull alignement features

```html
<script type="text/javascript" async src=
"https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.5/latest.js?config=
TeX-MML-AM_CHTML"></script>

<p style="width:100%;text-align:center;">
\(\begin{alignat}{3}
&[1]\hspace{63px}&&&{3-2} &&\ = 1 \hspace{63px}&&\text {More arithmetic}
\\&[2]&&&{E} &&\ = mc^2 &&\text {Feel the energy}
\\&[3]&&&{x+1} &&\ \color{red}{\unicode{x2B0C}} 5 &&\text{description}
\end{alignat}\)
</p>
```

**Edit**

```css
.unicode{
  transform-origin:50% 50%;  
  transform:scale(1.6,1.5);
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" async src=
"https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.5/latest.js?config=
TeX-MML-AM_CHTML"></script>


<p style="width:100%;text-align:center;">
\(\begin{alignat}{3}
 \\[2pt]\hline
&[1]\hspace{63px}&&&{3-2} &&\ = 1 \hspace{63px}&&\text {More arithmetic}
 \\[2pt]\hline
 &[2]&&&{E} &&\ = mc^2 &&\text {Feel the energy}
  \\[2pt]\hline
&[3]&&&{x+1} &&\ \color{red}{\class{unicode}{\unicode{x2B0C}}}\ 5 &&\text{description}
 \\[2pt]\hline
 \end{alignat}\)
</p>
```

You can set text style with `\class{className}` (but playing with font size will create shift that you have to correct with css rules. I'm not sure that it's what you want) and you can separate lines with `\hline` (and then adjust the vertical space as follow : `\\[2pt]\hline`.

As suggested in comment by @Xufox, you can also explore `\array` features to build a table. However, take not that:
https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2016/tabular-in-mathjax?answertab=active#tab-top (see also the comment above the question for how to use array)

Therefore, depending on what you want to achieve (e.g. something responsive), your solution maybe the easiest to set up.

Comment: Excellent - a lot simpler than my solution, with most capabilities in place. Two things: (1) are table borders an option? (2) enlarging the Unicode symbol de-aligns it vertically (as in CSS without corrections) - any workarounds?

Comment: Any way to cut the bottom row's extra top padding?

Comment: yes, see the second snippet I've just edited. Playing with transform and scale instead of increasing font size won't affect line spacing.

Comment: I see. As I intended to create a highly-flexible tables framework, I'll mark my approach as the 'answer' as I deem it more straightforward in that regard; added a reference to your approach. Thanks for your input.

Comment: I agree, your approach should be more flexible in all the sense of the word. However it's always good to know you have such possibilities